# How to solve: limactl is running under rosetta, please reinstall lima with native arch

Tags: homebrew, colima

After installing colima with homebrew I get the following error:

FATA[0000] limactl is running under rosetta, please reinstall lima with native arch
FATA[0001] lima compatibility error: error checking Lima version: exit status 1

I just installed it. I have a m2 machine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su] or [apple.se] (but please read their help documents to make sure before posting_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same issue. I tried lot of things. At last I have to uninstall Homebrew and install again. To uninstall use below command.

```
sudo /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

To install again Homebrew use below command

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

For colima `brew install colima`

Now you are good to go :)